# ionic3 - Didn't set nav root: invalid views to insert

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When I click a button this warning coming out which I running it in my web browser.`(ionic serve -l)`
[image]

I have `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>` in my **app.html** file, is it problem?

UPDATE:

button image (button in slide menu - feedback button)
[image]

**app.html**

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-list-header>导航栏</ion-list-header>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of loggedInPages" (click)="openPage(p)">
      <ion-icon item-start [name]="p.icon" [color]="isActive(p)"></ion-icon>
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
```

**app.components.ts**

```
  appPages: PageInterface[] = [
    { title: '新闻', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, index: 0, icon: 'ios-globe-outline' },
    { title: 'SOS', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, index: 1, icon: 'call' },
    { title: '服务', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, index: 2, icon: 'people' },
    { title: '反馈', name: 'FeedbackPage', component: FeedbackPage, icon: 'information-circle' },
    // { title: '机场志愿者入口', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, index: 0, icon: 'minan-sos' }
  ];
  loggedInPages: PageInterface[] = [
    { title: '新闻', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, index: 0, icon: 'ios-globe-outline' },
    { title: 'SOS', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, index: 1, icon: 'call' },
    { title: '服务', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, index: 2, icon: 'people' },
    { title: '反馈', name: 'FeedbackPage', component: FeedbackPage, icon: 'information-circle' },
    { title: '注销', name: 'TabsPage', component: TabsPage, icon: 'log-out', logsOut: true }
  ];

openPage(page: PageInterface) {
    let params = {};
        if (page.index) {
          params = { tabIndex: page.index };
        }

        if (this.nav.getActiveChildNavs().length && page.index != undefined) {
          this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0].select(page.index);
        } else {
          // Set the root of the nav with params if it's a tab index
          this.nav.setRoot(this.nav.setRoot(page.component, params), params).catch((err: any) => {
            console.log(`Didn't set nav root: ${err}`);
          });
        }

        if (page.logsOut === true) {
          // Give the menu time to close before changing to logged out
          this.userData.logout();
        }

  }
```

Comment: have you defined "rootPage" Page in component.ts file?

Comment: Show your button and its logic code

Comment: @Aman I did this 'rootPage = TabsPage;' in component.ts

Comment: @Duannx Sure I will update code now

Comment: please add `openPage` function code

Comment: @Duannx Sorry, forgot that, update already, check please

Comment: Does every button make that error or just some of them. Did you try  `this.app.getActiveNav()` instead of  `this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0]` (inject `private app: App` in `constructor`)

Comment: @Duannx"app"showing error when I changed it

Comment: @Duannx Any other solutions????

Comment: @YuyangHe: what error when you use app? It would be easier if you provide a live example reproduce your problem in [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/) or  [plnkr](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: @Duannx After I change my coding to 'this.app.getActiveNav()' , 'this.app.getActiveNav().select(page.index);' 'select' show error: "does not exit on type 'NavControllerBase'"

Comment: @Duannx Any other suggestion?

Comment: @YuyangHe: Lets discuss in chat

Comment: @Duannx Sure, iam inside already